Cite link for crypto.se?
Other Stack Exchange sites like Theoretical CS, Mathematics and Physics have cite links for questions and answers:

Since this site has a similarly academic focus, I think it might be useful to have that feature here as well, especially now after graduation. And even if it is not useful for many, it should not cause much clutter either.

Superb idea (especially, since we’re frequently linking up papers).
